# How to list AD users email addresses (if any) based on EmployeeID listed on txt file?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a long list of AD users EmployeesID:s and I need a listing of their email addresses.
I have id:s on txt file and tried to run:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\emp.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$IDs.$_'" -Properties EmailAddress |
        Select-Object EmailAddress, SamAccountName
} | Export-Csv .\results.csv
```

How could I get output from the list of email addresses of the users?

Comment: Also, search for whole ad forest would help

Comment: How does the format of the txt file look like

Comment: `"EmployeeID -eq '$IDs.$_'"` -> `"EmployeeID -eq '$_'"`, assuming that the input file contains just a list of IDs (one per line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working like this:

And the input was simply a employeeID perline in the text file

```
$id = Get-Content "C:\temp\emp.txt" 
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mail,EmployeeID
$Found = @()

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    if($id -contains $user.EmployeeID)
    {
        $Found += $user
    }
}
$found | Select-Object mail,SamAccountName | Export-CSV .\results.csv
```

Comment: did this: 
Get-Content C:\temp\EMP2.txt | 
foreach { Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=$_)" -properties emailaddress}| Out-File c:\temp\list2.txt
Seemed to give also the needed info, but Kages:s script gives much better listing. Cheers!